# How to track how many seconds a user listened to a song with google analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

So basically I have a simple javascript player, when the user clicks play a song starts and I track it with this code:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'player', 'play', 'songName', '0']);
```

This works perfect, now every 10 seconds I trigger this code again and I'm wondering if there is a way to tell google that this is the same song being listened by the same user just a few seconds extra.

maybe something like this:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'player', 'play', 'songName', '10']);
```

and then:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'player', 'play', 'songName', '20']);
```

and so on until it ends, but so far google seems to think that they are all different events.
Has anybody come across with something like this before? any ideas?

Comment: so why do you want to do that? the event api is designed for tracking events (as the name says), and "still listening" isnt an event...

Comment: Well I would like to know for how long each user listened to that particular song. The way it is right now, for example is a user listens to 50 seconds I'll have 5 event in GA, I'd like to have just 1 event instead

Comment: then send a stop event when he stops listening

Comment: @hereandnow78 the problem with waiting until the visitor stops listening to trigger the event is that there are a lot of ways a visitor can stop listening that would make it hard or impossible to trigger a GA event.  For example..visitor closes the browser, navigates to some other URL...

Comment: if the user isnt stopping the player itself (navigate to some other url, close the browser) you could listen to the window.onbeforeunload event, and trigger the stop event if the window is unloaded... i will add it as an answer and let you decide...

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK there isn't really an easy way to do this in GA (it's actually pretty easy in other report tools such as Omniture), but hey, you get what you pay for!  But here are some suggestions...

Instead of passing the current position of the song, pass how much was consumed from the previous event tick.  So in other words, every 10 seconds pop with a value of 10.  Then in your reports, in the metrics group,  you can use the "content" > "event value" metric to show the total amount. The main downside to this is that it will tell you how much of a song was listened to overall, but doesn't really tell you how far into the song people listened.  For example, if it says "100" then it could have been 1 person listening to 100 seconds or 10 people listening to 10 seconds. There are of course ways to get a little more granularity like average consumption overall, but no real buckets to speak of.

An alternative is to create buckets for % milestones reached. Most people do 10% increments or 25% increments. This is the more common way to do it, because it reduces the amount of requests made to GA, and makes for cleaner reports, less values to sort through (and if you think about it, knowing how many people listened to 36 seconds vs. 37 seconds of something is probably not very actionable).

It would look like this:

Initial Play

`_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'player', 'songName', 'play']);`

25% listened

`_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'player', 'songName', '25%']);`

50% listened

`_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'player', 'songName', '75%']);`

100% listened

`_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'player', 'songName', '100%']);`

Answer (score 0):

as i said in my comment. just trigger the start event, and if the user clicks the stop button, or leaves the page (onbeforeunload) push an stop event.

```
var isPlaying = false;
// the play start event
somestartbutton.onclick = function () {
   isPlaying = true;
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'player', 'songName', 'play']);
};


// the play start event
somestopbutton.onclick = function () {
  if (isPlaying) {
    isPlaying = false;
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'player', 'songName', 'stop']);
  }
};

// before the window is unloaded, which means the user leaves the page
window.onbeforeonload = function () {
  if (isPlaying) {
    isPlaying = false;
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'player', 'songName', 'stop']);
  }
}
```

of course you should refactor that a little bit and DRY that code a little bit up, but it should just give you an idea how it could solve your problem.